# Writing digits in Japanese

Tags: typesetting

Why are numbers written like `２０２０` and not `2020`?

Comment: May I ask you to explain a bit more about the context of your question? (Are you working on a [website](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/), just [curious](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/characters-encodings-and-globalization), ...?)

Comment: I don't think this is really on topic about the Japanese language, but you may be able to answer your own question here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms

Answer (score 3):

Kanji on average fill a roughly square space and tend to be most readable in monospace. So in Japanese typesetting when kanji is the predominant character set, you will usually see a monospace font full of roughly square glyphs. Latin alphabet characters and Arabic numerals look a little odd in this context.

Arabic numbers used in this context are also replacing their kanji equivalents. So, although the Arabic glyph is used, culturally they are not being used exactly as the western world uses them. Meaning, the perspective is that "2020" is four distinct characters that come together to have meaning. Rather than "2020" forming the equivalent of a word with a numeric value. The result is the same. But if you start out viewing them as separate characters, you may not want to make the font fit together graphically as a single word.